# Can i run my emulator manuel like in this picture?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

[Problem Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXPCE.png)
Hey guys. I just installed to flutter and android studio. So, I new installed to emulator. I started to follow a tutorial and in there, instructor's emulator's name was in the devices label but mine is not like  it(it says no devices.As i show in picture). Also, when i was click over devices button I can open my emulator. My question is, can my emulator work as manuel, with my manuel click or do you have any advices for me about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you start your emulator for the first time, you must authorize your computer to access it by enabling the `USB debugging` on it in the Phone Settings and by changing the `Use USB for` to `Transferring files`

Comment: But I dont using my phone for debug or run why i need to do that?

Comment: You must do this on your emulator not on your personal phone